# jQuery Plug-in Backstretch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this jQuery plug-in called [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) for full screen image. I've followed as instructed on their website but it's not working. Nothing is displayed.

I've first tried with local copies but it didn't work so I found CDN link but it didn't work either.

Having them inside `head` tag or just before the end of `body` didn't make difference.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$.backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
</script>
```

Does anyone have experience with this plug-in and have anything to share?

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that backstretch only works with jquery 1.8.3 - not newer versions, unfortunately.

Comment: Not an answer but rather a comment